# How to use variables in variables in crontab

Tags: linux, cron

I'm trying to use variables in variables in crontab:

```
AUTH=user:password
BASE_URL=http://...
COMMAND_OLDB=curl -u $AUTH $BASE_URL/openligadb >> /var/log/cron.openligadb.log
```

But just getting a mail in `/var/mail/root`:

```
X-Cron-Env: <BASE_URL=http://...>
X-Cron-Env: <AUTH=user:password>
X-Cron-Env: <COMMAND_OLDB=curl -u $AUTH $BASE_URL/openligadb >> /var/log/cron.openligadb.log>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
Message-Id: <...>
Date: Mon,  9 Feb 2015 20:10:01 +0100 (CET)

Enter host password for user '$AUTH':
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '$BASE_URL'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '>>'
curl: (3) <url> malformed
```

`/var/log/cron.openligadb.log` itself is empty.
`$AUTH` as well as `$BASE_URL` will not be resolved in `$COMMAND_OLDB`. Why and how to fix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to crontab man page (`man 5 crontab`)

- if you set variables, those will be environment variables (which is fine as long as you don't overwrite other environment variables)
- the value of such a variable is NOT parsed, substitutions will NOT work

So you can define `AUTH`, `BASE_URL` but you cannot define `COMMAND_OLDB` which is based on other variables, because those will not be substituted. Just put the command in the crontab line, like this (of course use your time interval)

```
*/10 * * * * curl -u $AUTH $BASE_URL/openligadb >> /var/log/cron.openligadb.log
```

but NOT like this

```
*/10 * * * $COMMAND_OLDB
```

Answer (score 1):

`crontab` has 2 types of statements (see `man 5 crontab`):

1. environment setting (e.g. `SHELL=/bin/bash`)
2. cron command (e.g. `* * * * * /path/to/cmd` )

The environment setting lines will not do variable substitution (e.g. `PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH`), but the cron command lines will. So you could just put the variable substitution line in the cron command instead of environment setting.

```sh
AUTH=user:password
BASE_URL=http://...

* * * * * COMMAND_OLDB="curl -u $AUTH $BASE_URL/openligadb" ; $COMMAND_OLDB >> /var/log/cron.openligadb.log
```

Note: This answer is more for educational purposes to demonstrate how it could be done. [Dan's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/875782/how-to-use-variables-in-variables-in-crontab/875821#875821) is the more practical answer.